# Any possibility to open new page as tab, not windows using groups of tabs

Tags: safari, links

How do I tell Safari to always open links as a new tab?

I know about "Prefer tabs when opening documents" option. But it doesn't work with groups of tabs. If I'm using some active group of tabs - it creates new window.

Answer (score 2):

Safari has its own pref, separate to the global one in Settings…

[image: Open Pages in tabs instead of windows]

Open Pages in tabs instead of windows